# Understanding Polish notation in Lukasiewicz's axioms

Tags: lo.logic, axioms

In a paper about Presburger Arithmetic, Lukasiewicz's axioms of propositional calculus are written as follows:

1. CCpqCCqrCpr
2. CCNppp
3. CpCNpq

I am having a hard time understanding what these axioms actually mean, as I have am not well versed in Polish notation. I know the first one is a form of modus ponens (if p implies q, and if q implies r, then p implies r), but I do not understand axioms 2 and 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a fine question, but not appropriate for this site, which is for research mathematics; a better fit would be math.stackexchange.

Comment: See [Łukasiewicz's axiom systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_systems#Implication_and_negation).

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, $C$ is the conditional, "if, then".  So
$$
CCpqCCqrCpr
$$
converted to infix notation, using $\rightarrow$ for the conditional:
$$
CCpqCCqrCpr
\\
(Cpq) \rightarrow (CCqrCpr)
\\
(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow ((Cqr) \rightarrow (Cpr))
\\
(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow ((q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r))
$$
The remarkable thing about "Polish notation" is that there is only one interpretation of each WFF.  So you eliminate mazes of parentheses.

The other two axioms use $N$ for negation.  Say, for example,  $Np$ is written $\overline{p}$.  Or maybe $\neg p$. I will let you work on them.